# rxjs-dom how to pass data into POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rxjs, rxjs-dom

I'm using `rx.DOM.ajax` https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md

I'm trying to get some data from a url using POST but it doesn't return anything.

Here's the code:

```
Rx.DOM.ajax({
    url: 'src/php/search.php',
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      extra: "Extra"
    }
  });
```

If I `print_r($_POST)` there's nothing in it. I'm expecting the server to receive a `$_POST`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue what the hell...

Comment: In my case was that I was trying to send body with 'GET' method, which doesn't work.

Comment: @Tomasz I just went with jquery's ajax :\

Answer (score 0):

Since rxjs-dom wasn't working I found another way.

Don't use rxjs-dom. It might be out of date. I went to use rxjs instead. Here's what I did (utilises jquery).

From my situation:

```
var search_bar = $("#search");
var textInput = $(search_bar);
var throttledInput =
      Rx.Observable.fromEvent(textInput, 'keyup')
        .pluck('target','value')
        .filter( function (text) {
            return text.length > 2;
        })
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged();

var suggestions = throttledInput.switchMap(term => term ? this.search(term) : "no term");
suggestions.subscribe(
  function (data)
  {
    console.log(data)
  },
  function (e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
);


search(value)
  {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "src/php/search.php",
      data: {
        name: value
      }
    }).promise();
  }
```

- First it gets the value from one of my inputs.
- Then it turns it into an observable from the value.
- debounceTime is used to prevent flooding the server if you're typing quickly
- distinctUntilChange is used so only new results are sent
- Lastly, it can utilise jquery, but must convert it back to promise.